Algorithm to find best score
I have a set of items with id and quantities, for example: { "item1": 4, "item2": 3, "item5": 1 }. Then I have a set of functions that take as input the item set, return an arbitrary score and a set of items used to get that score. For example, func1() may return a score of 123 and the quantity of each item consumed { "item1": 2, "item5": 1 } as items used. Those consumed items are subtracted from the original set and cannot be used in a subsequent function call. Assuming a function from the set is only called once, I need an algorithm that finds the order of function calls that maximize the score, without using permutation to test every possible order, because the number of functions may be around 30. I know that it seems like a case of the traveling salesman problem, or the knapsack problem, and algorithms like Held–Karp or dynamic programming may help, but I don't know how to apply that given that every function call changes the state (the set of items to be evaluated).
There is no simple logic as to why the functions return the score returned, they may be well considered opaque. The only rules are that a function will return which items were used and in which quantities and the resulting score, that may be zero in both cases; also, the functions may only use the items in quantities equal or less than the quantities present in the set fed, that gets decremented with the used items after each function. Each function will return always the same score/items used given the same input. The score can be considered always positive integers, as well as the quantities of the items.

Why do items 1 and 5 give a score of 123?

Are you looking for an optimal solution? Unless there are restrictions to the kind of functions you allow in the function set, it seems impossible to always get an optimal solution without testing all the permutations of function applications. I think it can be proved by an adversary argument.

I don't know why it's relevant for the problem, but you can imagine it, for example, like a best discount problem: items are what you buy in a supermarket, functions are different discounts and sales: you buy item2 and item5, you get 15% discount; you buy three item2, you get the last one for free, etc. So the score it's how much money you save using one sale or another, but once you used a sale, you cannot apply a different one over the same items: if you used the buy-three-pay-two for item2, you cannot get item2+item5 15% discount, because you already used the only three item2 you had.

@JohnSmithOptional yes, it should be the optimal solution.

@ravenspoint the relevance of the quantities is that a function may consume less than what is available of an item, and a subsequent function may consume what's left.

Where does the score ( e.g. 123 ) come from?  3rd time of asking.

The score appears to be arbitrary.  In which case then this IS a maximum flow problem.

@ravenspoint The score is arbitrary, I already edited the description.

Are the scores always positive integers?

@JohnSmithOptional yes, always positive integers

@ravenspoint I added a new example as to explain a possible use of the algorithm, at your request: "why do items 1 and 5 give a score of 123?". I already removed the second example and edited the question to specify the scores are arbitrary and the functions should be considered opaque.

Your question now makes sense to me.  It is a maximum flow problem: take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Can scores be negative?

@RaymondChen no, scores will always be positive.

Say we have a function F, and a multiset of items S1. If we have a subset S2 of S1, is the score F(S1) >= F(S2) guaranteed? I would intuitively assume so, and that would allow for some optimization if so.  As a follow on question, does the score returned by F depend on only the values it removes/consumes, or can it be impacted by other elements in the input multiset? If it only depends on the removed items, this could allow further optimizations.

@DillonDavis yes, it's guaranteed that F(S1) >= F(S2), and yes, the resulting score is only related to the removed items.

Why do you mention order of function calls? Order shouldn't matter, right? As long as the score of a function and amounts of items consumed depends only on which function, not on current amounts of items when it's called.

@Xellos if function A consumes item X and yields a score of 3, and function B consumes item X as well and yields a score of 5, when you have item X you will want function B first to maximize the score, otherwise function A will consume it yielding a lower score.

@Leandro If you only want B and not A, that's not order, that's just the (multi)set of functions to use. Finding order of functions means it matters if you call first B then A or first A then B.
